# Combined x numbers of attributed strings

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsmutableattributedstring

I want to ask how to combine x number of attributed string and make a single string.

```
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:health.storeArry];
            NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)array.count);
            for (NSDate * str in array) {
                NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
                dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
                NSString * dateTimeString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:str];

                NSString* str=dateTimeString;
                NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:str];

                [attrString addAttribute: NSFontAttributeName value:  [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15] range: NSMakeRange(str.length-2,2)];
                NSLog(@"%@",attrString);

                [attrString appendAttributedString:attrString];

}
```

This is my code. I found ans of two or three attibutedstring cancatenated but I have an array in which x number `nsdate` objects. I want to concatenate all of them in one string. How can I achieve that?
Thanks

Comment: What is not working in your code? You need to define a NSMutableAttributedString outside the for loop. Not related tip: You should alloc/init the `NSDateFormatter` outside the for loop. It's always the same one, and plus alloc/init of `NSDateFormatter` is consuming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you were creating each time a new `NSMutableAttributedString`. You need to put it outside the for loop.

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:health.storeArry];
NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)array.count);

NSMutableAttributedString *finalAttributedString = [NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;

for (NSDate *str in array) {

    NSString *dateTimeString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:str];

    NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:dateTimeString];

    [attrString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15] range:NSMakeRange(str.length-2,2)];
     NSLog(@"%@",attrString);

    [finalAttributedString appendAttributedString:attrString];

}
//Here, you can read the finalAttributedString
```

Not related tip: You should alloc/init the `NSDateFormatter` outside the for loop. It's always the same one, and plus alloc/init of `NSDateFormatter` is consuming.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this,

```
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"one",@"two",@"three", nil];
NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];

for (int i = 0; i < arr.count; i++) {

    str = [str stringByAppendingString:[arr objectAtIndex:i]];

}
NSLog(@"final str is %@",str);
```

hope this will help :)

Update :

You can convert  to `NSString` like,

```
NSString *str1 =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", nsattributedstring];
```

and then you can append it. so take attributed string from array convert it in nsstring and append it.

Comment: I want to combine the NSMutableAttributedString.... Your code is working for simplestring.

Comment: have you array of attributed string?

Comment: Actually you cant's use `stringByAppendingString` for attributed string.